# How to restrict access to non-scaffolded identity pages in .NET Core 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have created my .NET Core 7 web app and I have scaffolded some pages, such as 'Register', 'Login', 'Logout' and etc. However, for an example I have not scaffolded the 'PersonalData' page, yet if you add to the url 'Identity/Account/Manage/PersonalData' it would redirect you to it.

I can't seem to understand how can I restrict access to logged and non-logged users, so they can not access unscaffolded web pages.

I reckon it has something to do with the 'ManageNavPages.cs' since I see it goes through it when I debug it, but I am not sure I understand how it works, so I can stop it.

Here is my 'ManageNavPages.cs':

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace  Social_Media_App.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
    public static class ManageNavPages
    {
        public static string Index => "Index";
        public static string Email => "Email";
        public static string ChangePassword => "ChangePassword";
        public static string DownloadPersonalData => "DownloadPersonalData";
        public static string DeletePersonalData => "DeletePersonalData";
        public static string ExternalLogins => "ExternalLogins";
        public static string PersonalData => "PersonalData";
        public static string TwoFactorAuthentication => "TwoFactorAuthentication";
        public static string IndexNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, Index);
        public static string EmailNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, Email);
        public static string ChangePasswordNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, ChangePassword);
        public static string DownloadPersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, DownloadPersonalData);
        public static string DeletePersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, DeletePersonalData);
        public static string ExternalLoginsNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, ExternalLogins);
        public static string PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, PersonalData);
        public static string TwoFactorAuthenticationNavClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, TwoFactorAuthentication);
        public static string PageNavClass(ViewContext viewContext, string page)
        {
            var activePage = viewContext.ViewData["ActivePage"] as string
                ?? System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(viewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName);
            return string.Equals(activePage, page, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "active" : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I reckon it has something to do with the 'ManageNavPages.cs' since I
> see it goes through it when I debug it, but I am not sure I understand
> how it works, so I can stop it.

No `ManageNavPages.cs` is not the right place to implement authorization or anything related to control your user access and as per [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui.v5.pages.account.manage.internal.managenavpages.indexnavclass?view=aspnetcore-7.0#definition) this page shouldn't call from your user code as well. In addition to this, this implementation would be removed from subsequent release. [You can get more details here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui.v5.pages.account.manage.internal.managenavpages.indexnavclass?view=aspnetcore-7.0#definition)

Way to restrict access identity pages:

In order to restrict any page you could consider two most followed way.

**1.** Using authorization conventions in ASP.NET Core

**2.** Injecting SignInManager instance and check the user credentails.

**Using authorization conventions in ASP.NET Core:**

In asp.net core you would seen AuthorizeAreaPage convention where you can set any desired restriction which would add an AuthorizeFilter into it. You can do that as following:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
     options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Manage/PersonalData");
});
```

**Note:** Its better to include the PersonalData page within the project to avoid page non existent exception. You can [refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#require-authorization-to-access-a-folder-of-pages)

**Injecting SignInManager instance and check the user credentails:**

In this scenario, you can check the user credential before allowing to the access anhything within `ManageNavPages`. You can do that like below:

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@{
    var hasExternalLogins = (await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).Any();
}
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.IndexNavClass(ViewContext)" id="profile" asp-page="./Index">Profile</a></li>
    @if (hasExternalLogins)
    {
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext)" id="personal-data" asp-page="./PersonalData">Personal data</a></li>
    }
   
  
</ul>
```

**Note:** I have just used `hasExternalLogins`  in order to show how we can check restict the user. You can implement your suitable credential checkings or way to check valid user access then can allow/redirect to the expected page. [You can check the official document here.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Manage/_ManageNav.cshtml)